# MOSFET gets too hot when controlling a Peltier

Tags: arduino, mosfet, peltier

I want to control a Peltier element with an Arduino.

The idea is that I take the PWM of Arduino, turn this into analog with a low-pass filter (not in schematic) lower this voltage with a voltage divider, feed this into an opamp and use this signal to control a MOSFET.

[MOSFET datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FQP50N06-1009503.pdf)

[image]

The problem is that the MOSFET gets somewhere like 200 C with a 12 V 5 A DC adapter. What should I change in the circuit to make sure the MOSFET doesn't leave an imprint on my finger when I try to touch it?

Comment: Is STD30NF06L the MOSFET you are actually using? (because I know that people sometimes pick arbitrary MOSFETs for simulations)

Comment: You're operating the MOSFET in linear region. Depending on the Peltier element in question, your MOSFET needs to burn voltage drop across it times the current passing. What voltage and current does the Peltier need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the MOSFET on a big heatsink.  You are using it as a variable resistor.  It is going to generate heat - there's no way around that if you want an analog control of the Peltier device.

Alternatively, don't try to use it that way.

Discard the idea of PWM.  Turn the Peltier device fully on to cool.  Once the temperature gets where you want it, turn the Peltier completely off. When it gets too warm, turn it back on.  Allow a "dead band" temperature between on and off so that it isn't constantly (and quickly) switching on and off.

MOSFETs waste the least amount of power as heat when turned fully off or fully on.

---

Better still is to use a constant current switching power supply.

[Texas Instruments has an application report](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua979a/slua979a.pdf) about efficiency when driving Peltier elements.

Peltier elements don't seem to like PWM - they prefer a variable voltage or current drive.

MOSFETs don't like variable voltage - they're much better at switching on and off.

A constant current switching power supply uses a MOSFET to switch current on and off through an inductor.  The output has some ripple, but it is close enough to simple DC to make the Peltier happy.

The example given in the TI document won't fit your needs, though.  The IC used has a PWM input, but it switches the constant current output on and off to provide a dimmer function.

What you'll want instead is a way to change the current level.

Comment: thanks you so much! i'll give the on/off method a try. what would you advice in stead of the mosfet to turn on/off the power?

Comment: A MOSFET is fine to turn the Peltier device on and off.  The problem lies in using a MOSFET in between, so to speak.  Full on is fine, full off is fine.  In between it will get hot.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear why you are low pass filtering the PWM signal. By feeding the MOSFET an analogue signal, you are essentially switching it partially on, rather than fully on or off.

In this mode, there is a significant voltage across it, and so a large power dissipation.

MOSFETS are normally switched fully on or off, which is just what PWM is for.

Comment: JRE pointed out that PWMing a Peltier element is a bad idea because it loses efficiency.

Comment: yes. PWM is 40% less effective that constant power